# An odd way to write down a probability using fractions

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $k$ be a natural number and $X$ and random variable taking values
in $\left\{ 0,1,2,\ldots\right\} $. I recently saw someone claim
that 
$$
\mathbb{P}[X\geq k]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X|X\geq k]}.
$$

I believe I somehow must have understand something wrong, because
if I construct and easy example to test this formula, it fails (see below).

**Question 1: What changes does one have to make to the formula to make it true?**

Here's the counter-example: If
we toss a "two-sided" die (two-sided to make the counting
simpler), having numbers $1$ and $2$, and let $X$ count the number
of ones **in a sequences of 4 tosses**, and use $k=1$, then 
$$
\mathbb{P}[X\geq1]=\frac{15}{16},
$$
but $\mathbb{E}[X|X\geqslant1]=\mathbb{E}[X]$, so we would obtain
that $P[X\geq1]=1$.

(If I use $k=2$, I also do not get equality,
rather $\mathbb{E}[X|X\geq2]=\frac{28}{16}=1.75$.)

**Question 2: How to interpret "1.75"  in the last result?** Given the fact that we condition on $Z\geq 2$, I would have expected to obtain a result that is greater than 2.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what $X$ is - you said "let $X$ count the number of ones in a toss". So there can either be $0$ (i.e. you roll a $2$) or there can be $1$ one (i.e. you roll a $1$), hence $\Bbb P[X\geq1]=\Bbb P[X=1]=\frac12$, and $\Bbb E[X]=\frac12, \Bbb E[X|X\geq1]=1$, so it holds. Have you defined $X$ to be different to this? This seems likely, since you are considering $k>1$, which is an impossible event with my definition - could you clarify?

Comment: I am confused by the example. If $X$ is always $1$ or $2$, then the probability $X \geq 1$ is $1$, just as their formula said. Where'd you get that fraction?

Comment: @JohnDoe So sorry, I forgot to add that we toss the die in total 4 times! (The numbers that I computed also don't make sense otherwise.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your counterexample is wrong. Assuming (as clarified later) that we toss a die (or flip a coin) $4$ times and want to count the number of times $1$/heads comes up, we have $\mathbb E[X]=2$, $\mathbb E[X \mid X \ge 1] = \frac{1 \cdot \frac{4}{16} + 2 \cdot \frac{6}{16} + 3 \cdot \frac{4}{16} + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{16}}{\frac{4}{16} + \frac{6}{16} + \frac{4}{16} + \frac{1}{16}} = \frac{32}{15}$, and $\mathbb E[X \mid X \ge 2] = \frac{2 \cdot \frac{6}{16} + 3 \cdot \frac{4}{16} + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{16}}{\frac{6}{16} + \frac{4}{16} + \frac{1}{16}} = \frac{28}{11}$.

But the formula is also wrong: it correctly says $\mathbb P[X \ge 1] = \frac{2}{32/15} = \frac{15}{16}$, but incorrectly says $\mathbb P[X \ge 2] = \frac{2}{28/11} = \frac{11}{14}$ when $\mathbb P[X\ge2]$ is actually $\frac{11}{16}$.

Here's why. If we multiply to clear denominators, we get the incorrect formula
$$\color{red}{\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X \mid X\ge k] \cdot \mathbb P[X \ge k]}$$
as opposed to the correct way to deal with conditional expectation:
$$\color{blue}{\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X \mid X\ge k] \cdot \mathbb P[X \ge k] + \mathbb E[X \mid X < k] \cdot \mathbb P[X < k]}.$$
From here, if we write $\mathbb P[X < k]$ as $1 - \mathbb P[X \ge k]$ and solve for $\mathbb P[X \ge k]$, we can get $$\mathbb P[X \ge k] = \frac{\mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X \mid X<k]}{\mathbb E[X \mid X\ge k] - \mathbb E[X \mid X<k]}$$ which is the "correct version" of this formula.

---

Also, an inequality of this form holds: because $X$ is nonnegative, we have $$\mathbb E[X] \ge \mathbb E[X \mid X\ge k] \cdot \mathbb P[X \ge k]$$ by dropping the $\mathbb E[X \mid X < k] \cdot \mathbb P[X < k]$ term, and therefore $$\mathbb P[X \ge k] \le \frac{\mathbb E[X]}{\mathbb E[X \mid X \ge k]}.$$ This is tight exactly when the term we dropped was equal to $0$: either if $\mathbb P[X < k] = 0$, or else if $X=0$ whenever $X<k$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for providing the correct formula. I unfortunately forgot to add that we toss the die in total 4 times (then my numbers should make sense). Do you perhaps also have a reference for your formula?

Comment: I've edited the part about your counterexample. I don't have a reference for the formula itself, but the equation in blue is the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), which this is a transformation of.

Answer (score 0):

$$
E[X] = \sum_{n} P(X=n)/cdot n$$$$
E[X]/E[X|X\ge k] = \frac{\sum_n P(X=n)n}{\sum_{n\ge k} P(X=n) n / P(X\ge k)}
$$

Therefore

$$
P(X\ge k) = E[X]/\sum_{n\ge k} P(X=n)n
$$

Your counterexample is wrong, the expectation without conditioning is one half.

Answer (score 0):

$P(X\geq k) = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty}p_{X}(i)$ where $p_{X}(i)=P(X=i)$.

Now we have that $E[X]=\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}i \cdot p_{X}(i)$ and that $E[X|X\geq k]=\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{i\cdot p_X(i)}{1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}p_X(j)}$. Dividing these $2$ and noting that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p_{X}(i) = 1$ you get the desired result.

To elaborate on the conditional expectation bit: You can think about it as having cut a part of the probability distribution and you then have to normalise it so that the probabilities still sum up to 1

Comment: We only have $\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{i=k}^\infty i \cdot p_X(i)$ if $X$ can never be less than $k$; otherwise, you want the sum to start at $0$ instead.  So the formula as stated is only true in trivial cases where $\mathbb P[X \ge k] = 1$.

Comment: Yup, saw what you mean, it works only if the probabilities are 0 and we'll have to use conditional expectation. Will upvote your answer